# C++ templates as predicates for std::find_if: auto for parameters in lambdas vs free in functions vs templated functions

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, predicate, auto

Please do help to understand why **auto** for parameter in equivalent lambda will build correctly, but if I will use free function with **auto** for parameters, or templated functions, it won't. It's something I forgot about template deduction? Or new changes in C++?

Example to run (builts on MSVS 2022 compiler):

```
import <string>;
import <algorithm>;

auto isAllowedHandlerSymbolLambda = [](auto const& s)
{
    if (std::isalnum(s))
        return true;

    if (s == '_')
        return true;

    return false;
};

auto isAllowedHandlerSymbolFreeFunc(auto const& s)
{
    if (std::isalnum(s))
        return true;

    if (s == '_')
        return true;

    return false;
}

template< class Symbol >
auto isAllowedHandlerSymbolTemplateFunc(Symbol const& s)
{
    if (std::isalnum(s))
        return true;

    if (s == '_')
        return true;

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str{ "Something something, thank you for your time!" };
    std::find_if_not(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), isAllowedHandlerSymbolLambda); // yes!
    //std::find_if_not(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), isAllowedHandlerSymbolFreeFunc); // no
    //std::find_if_not(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), isAllowedHandlerSymbolTemplateFunc); // nope!
}
```

Comment: It's history: first there were templates (which solve it for free functions), then lambdas, then generic (auto) lambdas. The problem solved by `auto` for lambas is non-existent for functions - you already provided an alternative solution.

Comment: The lambda version is a non template class with a template operator() thus the class is known and can be used as a predicate. Fot the case with a function, the compiler does not know template type to use at that point. You need a specific instanciation here. In other word, it would need **bidirectionnal deduction** of type between `find_if_not` and `isAllowedHandlerSymbol[Free|Template]Func`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lambda are similar to functor class, not function:

```
struct lamba_unique_name
{
    template <typename T>
    auto operator()(const T& s) const { /* ...*/ }
    // ...
};
lamba_unique_name isAllowedHandlerSymbolLambda;
```

It is its operator which is templated, not the class,
So deduction for `std::find_if_not` predicate is just that type.

For your template functions, you would need to specify which specialization you  provide:

```
std::find_if_not(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), &isAllowedHandlerSymbolTemplateFunc<char>);
```